# React-Leaflet custom markers with condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, marker, react-leaflet

Hej!

I'm very new to leaflet and react and have an issue changing the icon of the marker based on a condition.

I want different colored markers based on the project and set the opacity based on the status given in a json file.

I defined my icons, create functions for every condition and try to return it likewise the map.

```
//map.js - giving an empty website (totally blank)

import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import dummy_data from '../../data/dummy_data.json';
import L from 'leaflet';

function Map() {

    const greenIcon = new L.Icon({
        iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-green.png',
        shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
        iconSize: [25, 41],
        iconAnchor: [12, 41],
        popupAnchor: [1, -34],
        shadowSize: [41, 41],
    });

    const blueIcon = new L.Icon({
        iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-blue.png',
        shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
        iconSize: [25, 41],
        iconAnchor: [12, 41],
        popupAnchor: [1, -34],
        shadowSize: [41, 41]
    });


    function CreateGreenMarker() {
        dummy_data.map(element => {
            if (element.ProjektorgaList == 'DBFZ' && element.active == true) {
                <Marker 
                    key = {element.projektNr}
                    position={[element.Latitude, element.Longitude]}
                    icon={greenIcon}>
                <Popup>
                    {element.LeadOrga}
                </Popup>
            </Marker>
            };
         })}
      
    function CreateGreenOpacMarker() {
        dummy_data.map(element =>{
        if (element.ProjektorgaList == 'DBFZ' && element.active == false) {
            <Marker 
            key = {element.projektNr}
            position={[element.Latitude, element.Longitude]}
            icon={greenIcon}
            opacity={0.4}>
                <Popup>
                    {element.LeadOrga}
                </Popup>
            </Marker>
        };
    })}


        function CreateBlueMarker() {
            dummy_data.map(element =>{
            if (element.ProjektorgaList.includes(';') && element.active == true) {
                <Marker 
                key = {element.projektNr}
                position={[element.Latitude, element.Longitude]}
                icon={blueIcon}>
                    <Popup>
                        {element.LeadOrga}
                    </Popup>
                </Marker>
            };
        })}
    
        function CreateBlueOpacMarker() {
            dummy_data.map(element =>{
            if (element.ProjektorgaList.includes(';') && element.active == false) {
                <Marker 
                key = {element.projektNr}
                position={[element.Latitude, element.Longitude]}
                icon={blueIcon}
                opacity={0.4}>
                    <Popup>
                        {element.LeadOrga}
                    </Popup>
                </Marker>
            };
        })}
    
    return (
        <MapContainer 
            center={[51.00, 10.00]}
            zoom={6}
            maxZoom={18}
            scrollWheelZoom={true}
        >
            <TileLayer
                url='http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png '
                attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            />
            
            <CreateBlueMarker/>

            <CreateBlueOpacMarker/>

            <CreateGreenMarker/>

            <CreateGreenOpacMarker/>

        </MapContainer>
    );
  }
  
  export default Map;
```

I'm not getting any error message, but the website is totally blank.

If I'm only rendering default markers everything works fine.

```
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import dummy_data from '../../data/dummy_data.json';
import L from 'leaflet';

function Map() {
    
    return (
        <MapContainer 
            center={[51.00, 10.00]}
            zoom={6}
            maxZoom={18}
            scrollWheelZoom={true}
        >
            <TileLayer
                url='http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png '
                attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            />
            
        {dummy_data.map(data => ( 
          <Marker 
           key = {data.projektNr}
           position={[data.Latitude, data.Longitude]}>
           <Popup>
                {data.LeadOrga}
            </Popup>
        </Marker>
    ))}

        </MapContainer>
    );
  }
  
  export default Map;
```

Leaflet without react is working fine. I can get all my markers with the right conditions.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>OrgaKarte</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
            integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
            crossorigin=""/>

        <style>
            #map {
                margin-top: 20px;
                margin-left: 200px;
                height: 600px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>


    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
        crossorigin=""></script>


        <script>

            // dummy data for testing

            const dummy_data = [
                {
                "projektNr": "03EI5433",
                "Acronym": "HTPyr1",
                "ProjektorgaList": "VauTe",
                "LeadOrga": "Biomasse GmbH",
                "Longitude": 9.932966,
                "Latitude": 49.79245, 
                "active": 'True'
                },
                {
                "projektNr": "1234",
                "Acronym": "HTPyr1",
                "ProjektorgaList": "VauTe",
                "LeadOrga": "Biomasse GmbH",
                "Longitude": 13.00,
                "Latitude": 49.00, 
                "active": 'True'
                },
                {
                "projektNr": "1234",
                "Acronym": "HTPyr1",
                "ProjektorgaList": "DBFZ",
                "LeadOrga": "Biomasse GmbH",
                "Longitude": 13.00,
                "Latitude": 50.00, 
                "active": 'False'
                },


            // initial map

            var map = L.map('map').setView([51.00, 10.00], 6);

            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png ', {
                styles: 'c',
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }).addTo(map);


            // icon choices

            var greenIcon = new L.Icon({
                iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-green.png',
                shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
                iconSize: [25, 41],
                iconAnchor: [12, 41],
                popupAnchor: [1, -34],
                shadowSize: [41, 41],
            });

            var blueIcon = new L.Icon({
                iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-blue.png',
                shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
                iconSize: [25, 41],
                iconAnchor: [12, 41],
                popupAnchor: [1, -34],
                shadowSize: [41, 41]
            });

            

            // create the markers
            // including pop ups, opacity, colour
            
            dummy_data.map(element =>{
                if (element.ProjektorgaList == 'DBFZ' && element.active == 'True') {
                    L.marker([element.Latitude, element.Longitude], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup(element.LeadOrga + '<br/><a href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test" target="_blank">mehr Informationen</a>').on('mouseover', function (e) {
                     this.openPopup();
                 }); 
                }
                 if (element.ProjektorgaList == 'DBFZ' && element.active == 'False') {
                    L.marker([element.Latitude, element.Longitude], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map).setOpacity(0.4).bindPopup(element.LeadOrga + '<br/><a href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test" target="_blank">mehr Informationen</a>').on('mouseover', function (e) {
                     this.openPopup();
                 });             
                }
                if (element.ProjektorgaList == 'VauTe' && element.active == 'True') {
                    L.marker([element.Latitude, element.Longitude], {icon: goldIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup(element.LeadOrga + '<br/><a href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test" target="_blank">mehr Informationen</a>').on('mouseover', function (e) {
                     this.openPopup();
                 }); 
                }
                 if (element.ProjektorgaList == 'VauTe' && element.active == 'False') {
                    L.marker([element.Latitude, element.Longitude], {icon: goldIcon}).addTo(map).setOpacity(0.4).bindPopup(element.LeadOrga + '<br/><a href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test" target="_blank">mehr Informationen</a>').on('mouseover', function (e) {
                     this.openPopup();
                 });             
                }
                if (element.ProjektorgaList.includes(';') && element.active == 'True') {
                    L.marker([element.Latitude, element.Longitude], {icon: blueIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup(element.LeadOrga + '<br/><a href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test" target="_blank">mehr Informationen</a>').on('mouseover', function (e) {
                     this.openPopup();
                 }); 
                }
                 if (element.ProjektorgaList.includes(';') && element.active == 'False') {
                    L.marker([element.Latitude, element.Longitude], {icon: blueIcon}).addTo(map).setOpacity(0.4).bindPopup(element.LeadOrga + '<br/><a href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test" target="_blank">mehr Informationen</a>').on('mouseover', function (e) {
                     this.openPopup();
                 });             
                }
            });           
            

            // if filter:
            // function to set the zoom and change the center
            // map.setZoom(8); -> for a Bundesland?
            // map.panTo(new L.LatLng('new center')); -> pan in to the new given filter


            /*
            function filter (datalist.option) {
                if (datalist.option.value = "Bayern")
                map.setZoom(8);
                map.panTo(new L.LatLng('48.790447', '11.497889'))
            }
            */


            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

my json file looks like this:

```
[
  {
  "projektNr": "03EI5433",
  "Acronym": "HTPyr1",
  "ProjektorgaList": "VauTe",
  "LeadOrga": "Biomasse GmbH",
  "Longitude": 9.932966,
  "Latitude": 49.79245, 
  "active": true
  },
  {
  "projektNr": "1234",
  "Acronym": "HTPyr1",
  "ProjektorgaList": "VauTe",
  "LeadOrga": "Biomasse GmbH",
  "Longitude": 13.00,
  "Latitude": 49.00, 
  "active": true
  },
  {
  "projektNr": "1234",
  "Acronym": "HTPyr1",
  "ProjektorgaList": "DBFZ",
  "LeadOrga": "Biomasse GmbH",
  "Longitude": 13.00,
  "Latitude": 50.00, 
  "active": false
  },
  {
  "projektNr": "03EI5433",
  "Acronym": "HTPyr1",
  "ProjektorgaList": "Biomasse GmbH; DBFZ; Mustermann AG; Test AG; VauTe",
  "LeadOrga": "Biomasse GmbH",
  "Longitude": 12.932966,
  "Latitude": 52.79245, 
  "active": true
  },
  {
  "projektNr": "12345",
  "Acronym": "Hallo",
  "ProjektorgaList": "Biomasse GmbH; DBFZ; Test AG; VauTe",
  "LeadOrga": "Biomasse GmbH",
  "Longitude": 10.00,
  "Latitude": 50.00, 
  "active": true
  },
  {
  "projektNr": "Test",
  "Acronym": "Test",
  "ProjektorgaList": "Test2; Hallo",
  "LeadOrga": "Test2",
  "Longitude": 11.00,
  "Latitude": 53.00,
  "active": false
  }
]
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to implement the conditions in my react-leaflet?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you create a demo for that? It is not so much comprehensive as you describe it right now.

Comment: Do you see your map with zoom control and Tile Layer at least?

Comment: I hope everything is clearer now, I edited my question and code examples. (unfortunatly I can't get a snippet running in SO, even if it works when running the app.)

Comment: With my conditions in react-leaflet I see nothing, just a white/blank page. 

Without the defined functions and markers I can see blue default markers and my zoom-map.

Only leaflet, without react, I can see the map and multiple colored markers, with different opacity.